# What was the file that has rot13 coding in Python and what was the name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rot13

I remember that there was a file in Python `something.py` that has rot13 coding. It has `for` loops and variables like `d,c` etc. Can anyone tell me that the name of that file and where is it in Python 3.5?

Edit: It's a module coming with Python, not 3rd party.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PEP-20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

```
import this
print(this.s)
```

The source code can be found at:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/this.py